# Make Up the XML View

Tags: android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" android:layout_marginRight="10dip" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/gray_bg" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:text="Offers" android:layout_marginRight="10dip"    android:background="@drawable/gray_btn"
            android:id="@+id/button1"   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
        <Button android:text="Daily Deals" android:layout_marginRight="10dip"   android:background="@drawable/gray_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button2">
        </Button>
        <Button android:text="Photos" android:layout_marginRight="10dip" android:background="@drawable/gray_btn"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:text="Videos" android:layout_marginRight="10dip" android:background="@drawable/gray_btn"
            android:id="@+id/btnVideos"     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
        <Button android:text="Maps" android:layout_marginRight="10dip" android:background="@drawable/gray_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button2">
        </Button>
        <Button android:text="Email" android:layout_marginRight="10dip" android:background="@drawable/gray_btn"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <Button android:id="@+id/btnRecommend"
             android:background="@drawable/recommend_btn"
             android:scaleType="fitXY" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:onClick="btnSubNavigationPressed" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
             </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
  
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to make the last button width equals to just the above tow rows of buttons,

How i can do this, please give me any hint to do this.

Comment: please any one provide me the solution, i really need this

Comment: is the attached image how the xml layout look or how you want it to look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do in two ways:

either:

```
android:layout_span="3"
```

or

```
android:layout_weight="1" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="0dip"
```

may one of this work for you...

Comment: Hey thanks, I implement your first suggestion, but by this my last button has cuts from right side, I add the actual xml file, so please give me hint how i can do this in right way.

Comment: there may be problem with your android:paddingRight="21dip" try altering it or use margin instead...